# `git status` shows worktree folders

Tags: git

I have created a worktree in my git project (feature of git >= 2.5). It resides in a sub folder of the root project folder and is called `wt-something`.
Now when I issue `git status` from within the root project folder the worktree folder is shown among other untracked files as `untracked file`.
Isn't it supposed the worktree folders not to be shown in git status?
Or I do have to specify them explicitly in `.gitignore`?

Comment: `git status <branch>` works for me

Comment: Another approach would be to create a worktree beside your root folder like `git worktree add ../worktree-name` but here you would need to do npm install to make the packages available to your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git Worktree works by creating a new subfolder which acts like a new branch.  This folder contains, among other things, a `.git` file for the worktree branch.  When you type `git status` the worktree folder shows up under untracked files.  This makes sense, because from the point of view of your current branch, the worktree is just a bystander with no direct influence.

Untracked files will *not* prevent you from doing any work (push, pull, etc.) on your current main branch.